# Ubuntu 19.04 Lenovo 330s 15arr touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, 19.04, ideapad, amd-ryzen

My trackpad is not working, I read about upgrade to kernel version `4.19.15` on ubuntu `18.04`, but my current Kernel is `5.0`.

What can I do?

My laptop is a *Lenovo [ideapad 330s-15ARR](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330s-15arr_hmm_201805.pdf)* with

- AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with the latest BIOS update
- Ubuntu 19.04.
- Windows 10

Comment: Detail: It has UEFI, not BIOS (even if the manufacturer still call it BIOS it ain't so). Have you installed in UEFI mode or Legacy?

Comment: I installed in UEFI mode and I had the same problem, but now I have it installed in legacy mode

Comment: If you want Grub to work for both it must be in the same mode. Also SATA mode must be AHCI. If doable, after enabling AHCI, reinstall both in UEFI mode.

Comment: i was uninstall that UEFI mode version and reinstall in Legacy mode

Comment: Any UEFI machine should be installed in UEFI mode. Legacy is only for OSes without UEFI support which is not the case (Win7 must be installed with USB for UEFI mode).

Comment: 5.0 is the kernel version which comes with Ubuntu 19.04 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes so that's normal.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks, i`ll reinstall in uefi mode again

Comment: @K7AAY yeah, i know, my question is about the trackpad

Comment: So the better chance you have for all the hardware working as it should is installing in the correct mode. If it still doesn't work with the newer kernel we troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Tell me output of `sudo acpidump | grep -C3 ELAN`

Comment: The device may not be included in kernel. For 330-15arr touchpad was working with 4.19+ kernel, 330s may have a different touchpad device.

Comment: i'm reinstall in UEFI mode and i have the same problem

Comment: @SauravSingh
    5CE0: 50 12 06 01 47 50 49 4F 14 39 5F 48 49 44 00 A0  P...GPIO.9_HID..
    5CF0: 13 93 54 43 50 44 0A 02 A4 0D 53 59 4E 41 33 32  ..TCPD....SYNA32
    5D00: 35 35 00 A0 13 93 54 43 50 44 0A 03 A4 0D 41 4C  55....TCPD....AL
    5D10: 50 53 31 32 31 45 00 A4 0D 45 4C 41 4E 34 36 39  PS121E...ELAN469
    5D20: 44 00 08 45 49 43 30 11 21 0A 1E 8E 19 00 01 00  D..EIC0.!.......
    5D30: 01 02 00 00 01 06 00 80 1A 06 00 15 00 5C 5F 53  .............\_S
    5D40: 42 2E 49 32 43 44 00 79 00 08 53 49 43 30 11 21  B.I2CD.y..SIC0.!

Comment: Are you on latest bios?

Comment: @SauravSingh yes, i'm, the version is `7WCN35WW`

Answer (score 1):

> I have found a workaround to solve touchpad problem.
>
> This helped me https://superuser.com/questions/1052023/ioapic0-not-in-ivrs-table and thanks to my friend who had 330s-15arr. I can confirm that it works.
>
> Note: I have tested it on Ubuntu 18.04 with custom 4.19 kernel.

**Requirements:** Must be on latest bios version 7WCN35WW. And ubuntu must be installed in UEFI mode.

First upgrade to latest mainline kernel (not needed you can try on stock kernel too) and edit the file `/etc/default/grub` by adding `ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0` to grub kernel boot parameter and run `sudo update-grub` then reboot and see if touchpad works, Make sure to remove other kernel parameters except `quiet splash`, if it doesn't work follow the rest steps.

**Now what you have to do is. Build a kernel.**

Follow below steps ([Source](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx/Lenovo-Ideapad-330-15ARR-ryzen-5-bios-doesn-t-support-linux/m-p/4251437/highlight/true#M61640))

> to fix touchpad(not that easy if you havent compiled a kernel yet,not that difficult either)
>
> 1. download any kernel source from kernel.org (better choose the version that you are running presently or just the next updated version of it)
>        *use the command `uname -a` to find the current kernel version
> 2. extract the kernel source and find the file `17.4.xx/drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_core.c`
> 3. locate the line `{ "ELAN061C", 0 }` edit that `61C` to `61E` and save that file
> 4. compile and use your new kernel
>
> (this link may help if you are a newbie in kernel compiling.I simply followed it-https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-and-installing-the-latest-linux-kernel-from-source-6d8df5345980)

After that, if you are lucky you don't have to do anything else.

Now if your touchpad doesn't work even after compiling the kernel then make sure `ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0` is added to grub kernel boot parameter and run `sudo
update-grub` then reboot.

If still touchpad does not work then check `dmesg` for errors and post as comment. Make sure to follow the kernel compiling guide by patience and correctly if you have to build you own kernel and you are doing it first time, before reporting errors.

Comment: sorry, there is https://pastebin.com/Gb8Lm1EU

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro can you post full dmesg?

Comment: yes: https://pastebin.com/6PGcZy8j

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro Have you added `ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0`? If you have other kernel parameters like `noapic` then remove them and update grub then reboot. I tried on fresh 19.04 install touch pad works with stock kernel but adding `ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0` is necessary.

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro I think the issue is with `[    6.968349] i2c_designware AMDI0010:01: controller timed out`

Comment: If, I don't add `noapic` in kernel parameters, the screen it goes black and does not load the ubuntu image

Comment: yes, I'm add `ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0`

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro In my friend's laptop `noapic` make the touchapad useless again, and it boots without `noapic`, strange. You must check kernel output during boot after removing noapic to see what is causing issue.

Comment: There are no output, the screen is black and the hotkeys do nothing

Comment: I follow your instructions. Bit I didn't actually compile the whole kernel. I follow this instructions for the kernel part https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=281790 Now it works pertfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem with touchpad entry in `/sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol`
Checkout [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1143740/956680) fix

It's evident from your pastebin file that you don't have any pointers to your touchpad or trackpoint.

`egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices`

this will tell you the type of driver,if it is available.

Then try to add that touchpad entry into `/sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol`

Comment: that its the output when i run that command `sh: 1: cannot create /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol: Directory nonexistent`

Comment: can you paste the contents of `xinput list`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BkEUPAdN

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro Did you try this updated answer?

Comment: i was run `sudo egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices` and don't have output

Comment: i was checking de path and `serio1` folder doesn't exist

Comment: I reinstalled the OS and serio1 dir doesn't appear