# Touchpad not working in Lenovo Thinkpad L480 after ugrading to ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad, 19.04

I have upgraded my system from 18.04 to 19.04.
after upgrading to 19.04 my touchpad is not working.

My kernel version

```
lohit@stormbreaker:~$ uname -a
Linux stormbreaker 5.0.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 17:41:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my `xinput list`:

```
lohit@stormbreaker:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried installing,
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
after installing, my synclient says no synaptics driverloaded.

```
lohit@stormbreaker:~$ synclient
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

I dont find any touchpad device under `/proc/bus/input/devices`

```
lohit@stormbreaker:~$ cat  /proc/bus/input/devices 
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0101 Product=0007 Version=0111
N: Name="USB OPTICAL MOUSE "
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0101:0007.0001/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=17aa Product=5054 Version=4101
N: Name="ThinkPad Extra Buttons"
P: Phys=thinkpad_acpi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=33
B: KEY=10040 0 18040000 0 50000000000000 0 1701b02102004 c000280051115000 10e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10
B: SW=8

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=5986 Product=2113 Version=5422
N: Name="Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-7/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

after trying to fix from some online sources my grub looks like this:

```
lohit@stormbreaker:~$ sudo cat  /etc/default/grub
[sudo] password for lohit: 
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
psmouse.elantech_smbus=0
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I have checked if there are any updates availabe, and i am up to date.

please help me solve this issue

Comment: FWIW I have a Lenovo T440s. In `/proc/bus/input/devices` the touchpad is listed as: `I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1 N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0 S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5 U: Uniq= H: Handlers=mouse0 event4  B: PROP=15 B: EV=b B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0 B: ABS=660800011000003`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem with my ThinkPad. Found this temporary fix from the arch forums:

sets 'elantech' as the protocol for serial device with the command:

`sudo sh -c 'echo -n "elantech" > /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol'`

Comment: its working after running the command, Thank you.
my xinput list shows this
 
```
lohit@stormbreaker:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech TrackPoint               id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                 id=14 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ ..
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution works great! However, I found that it resets on reboot. The post below has a kernel option you can add to grub so that it's fixed on boot.

[Elantech - Touchpad not working after upgrading to 18.10 from 18.04 (ThinkPad L480)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091635/elantech-touchpad-not-working-after-upgrading-to-18-10-from-18-04-thinkpad-l4)

In `/etc/default/grub` I added `psmouse.elantech_smbus=0` to the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and everything worked perfectly after doing `sudo update-grub` and rebooting.

For reference, I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad L390 Yoga. My touchpad was working, but clicking it only registered as a left click. I couldn't right click or drag with two fingers.