# My touchpad not working?

Tags: system-installation, touchpad, 19.04, synaptics

I upgraded Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 . I saw some error messages while installation and I avoid it . But after installation my touchpad is not working. touchpad is `on` in settings-> devices -> mouse & touchpad.  please help me

```
asru@asru-HP-Notebook:~$ paste /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol
SynSMBus
```

after I running this  command touchpad working comfortably

```
asru@asru-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo -n "synaptics" > /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol'
asru@asru-HP-Notebook:~$
```

and protocol was changed

```
asru@asru-HP-Notebook:~$ paste /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol
SynPS/2
```

but this way is unstable its resets on reboot.
Give me a stable way to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste the contents of `uname -a`

and

`xinput list`

Possible solution :
https://askubuntu.com/a/1143740/956680

Comment: its works till only i restart my system and it doesn't support multi touch

Comment: try adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.elantech_smbus=0` to `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: sorry.! my touchpad is synaptics not elantech

Comment: can I  use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0` instead of this

Comment: yeah you can add and check your boot params at`cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: Thank you.! that is worked